Why does Perl behave as if a deep copy wasn't made only when using <<>>?
In my code, I first stored the values of @ARGV in @argv, then iterated over @argv using foreach. Inside the loop, I assigned each element of @argv to @ARGV and used <<>> to process files one by one. After the loop finished, I intended to run another loop over @argv to rename the processed files as hidden files. I expected this to work correctly, but just before the final foreach loop, I found that @argv was empty. I tested similar scenarios using shift and delete, but in those cases, the original array was unaffected, as if a deep copy had been made. I'm not sure why using <<>> affects the original array when it doesn't happen with shift or delete.
my %argv_parsed = &parse_arguments();
my @argv        = @ARGV;
# ...

$^I = $backup_enabled ? '.bak' : '';

foreach (@argv) {
    my $file_name  = $_;
    my $is_in_code = 0;
    # ...

    @ARGV = $file_name;

    while (<<>>) {
        $is_in_code = ! $is_in_code if /^`\``/;

        if ($is_in_code || ! /^( {0,3})(#{1,6})(.+)/) {
            print;
            next;
        }

        my ($pre_space, $hash, $title) = ($1, $2, $3);

        $title =~ s/^ +(\d*\.){1,6}// if $is_marked;

        # ...

        say "$pre_space$hash " . (join '.', @head_number_interim) . ".$title";
    }

    unless ($is_marked) {
        open FILE, '>>', $file_name;
        say FILE $mark_comment;
        close FILE;
    }
}

exit 0 unless $backup_enabled;

foreach (map { "$_$^I" } @argv) {
    my ($name, $path) = fileparse $_;

    rename "$path$name", "$path.$name";
}



You used
foreach (@ARGV)

which aliases each element of @ARGV as $_.
Later on, you use
while (<<>>) {

which assigns each line read from the file into $_. When EOF is encountered, $_ is set to undef. As it's aliased to an element of @ARGV, after processing all the files, @ARGV contains just undefs.
This shows it:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @argv = @ARGV;

for (@argv) {
    print Dumper \@argv;
    @ARGV = $_;
    while (<<>>) {
        1
    }
}

Naming the script 2.pl and running it as ./2.pl 2.pl 2.pl 2.pl:
$VAR1 = [
          '2.pl',
          '2.pl',
          '2.pl'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          '2.pl',
          '2.pl'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          '2.pl'
        ];

Moral: Use named variables instead of $_ in more complex loops.

The typical advice is that you don't modify the control variable or the data source in a loop. For example, read the perlfunc entry on each.

foreach (@argv) {
    #...
    while (<<>>) {

That is two loops, nested, both using $_. Don't Do That. Use an assigned loop param on at least one of them, preferably both.
foreach my $arg (@argv) {
    # ...
    my $input;
    while ($input = <<>>) {


Sure, but what do you think is left to read from <<>> after that while has finished and you're on the second iteration of the foreach?

Duh! Totally missed that.

I think your structure here is overly complicated. You say:

After the loop finished, I intended to run another loop over @argv to rename the processed files as hidden files.

So, I think you want something like this, where you do the first thing, then when you are done with all the file, do the next thing:
# process all the lines:
while( <<>> ) { ... }

# rename
foreach my $file (@ARGV} { rename ... }

Or, do things one file at a time and don't think about <> with the default file handle at all:
foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or ...;
    while( <$fh> ) { ... }
    rename $file, ...
    }

